# How do I get the properties of a class as object literal type?

Tags: typescript, class, generics

Below I have a `Signup` class that extends `Joke`.

What I'm trying to have is `v` have a type error, where username cannot be a number, but the generic `ObjectProps` is not properly getting at the props of `Signup`.

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwM7AE4FcDGw6qgXigQgHcoAKAOmoENUBzJALihoRAG0BdASgID4oAbwC+AKDGhIUAPIAjAFYRsABVRwwSADwAVKBAAewCAgAmSWIhQZsuADRQAavqMnzl5Giw48AHyjoZhAAZgCWxKYEAUFhEYKEMgC2ocBaQmJQmVAcANZQ4VA5ECBwwVA6XCw6uVxiIg5FJWWO-BKYADY0SBYAUnBFwhlZbCDAABbh9ABycMAAkggyqKH04TTtLHJwcO0QbFFeEHVtnd1QAMorCOhgLsZmvf3Q6Vn6iTShG1DWk1EA5H8hpl0EgIKgEDREhAWD8EPR-oDXmAukgSLhTDC0L9CADjpJwNADFF5EpVOpNFopBBShcrjcHFSaX0iq0xJgrMAoAA3FhEwgvLIgsEQqEsACMdSAA)

```
type Constructor = new (...args: any[]) => {}

type ObjectProps<T extends Constructor, V extends Constructor | undefined = undefined> = Omit<{
    [k in keyof T]: T[k]
}, keyof V>

class Joke {
    anythingNotInOriginal: boolean = true
}

class Signup extends Joke {
    email: string = ''
    username: string = ''
    password: string = ''
}

type x = ObjectProps<typeof Signup, typeof Joke>

const v: x = {
    username: 1
}
```

How can I have `x` have the following signature:

```
{ email: string, username: string, password: string }
```

And be derived from the `Signup` class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @jcalz mentioned in the comments, this works

```
const v: Omit<Signup, keyof Joke> = {
    email: '',
    username: '',
    password: ''
}
```